# How to apply only security updates on CentOS?

Tags: linux, security, centos, updates, yum

Ive tried what [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-fedora-centos-linux-yum-installs-security-updates/) describes:

```
yum install yum-security
```

Next step is

```
yum list-security
```

but the result of this is:

`Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.anl.gov
 * epel: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Killed`

Any idea why it gets killed? I don't care *how* if there is another way to do it I'm fine with that as well.

The system version is this

> 2.6.32-042stab088.4 #1 SMP Sat Jun 21 00:15:09 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Edit:**

Running `yum clean all` and then trying it again didn't help:

```
[root@foobar  burzum]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Cleaning repos: atrpms base epel extras nginx updates vz-base vz-updates webtatic
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
[root@florian-kraemer burzum]# yum list-security
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                  |  14 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.corenetworks.net
 * epel: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
 * updates: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
atrpms                                                         | 3.0 kB     00:00
atrpms/primary_db                                              | 1.7 MB     00:01
base                                                           | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                | 4.6 MB     00:02
epel                                                           | 4.4 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                | 6.3 MB     00:03
extras                                                         | 3.3 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                              |  19 kB     00:00
nginx                                                          | 2.9 kB     00:00
nginx/primary_db                                               |  34 kB     00:00
updates                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                             | 156 kB     00:00
vz-base                                                        |  951 B     00:00
vz-base/primary                                                | 1.3 kB     00:00
vz-base                                                                           3/3
vz-updates                                                     |  951 B     00:00
vz-updates/primary                                             | 2.2 kB     00:00
vz-updates                                                                        8/8
webtatic                                                       | 3.6 kB     00:00
webtatic/primary_db                                            | 167 kB     00:00
epel/updateinfo                                                | 858 kB     00:00
Killed
[root@foobar burzum]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this is typically due to memory exhaustion.  The security plugin seems to use extra memory.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck implementing articles from 2009. CentOS 6/7 doesn't supply "security" categories inside package metadata (unlike RHEL), so  nevermind what yum plugin magic you use, it won't do.

The best practice is to update all, and in my practice the complete updates are still conservative enough so that problems are very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution: [Centos Security updates only](https://www.caseylabs.com/centos-automatic-security-updates-do-not-work/)

```
sudo yum install yum-plugin-changelog pcre-devel python-pip
mkdir /var/lib/centos-package-cron
pip install centos_package_cron

centos-package-cron --output stdout --forceold | pcregrep -M 'Packages:[^:]*' | grep -o "[^* ]*" | grep -v 'Packages:' | grep -v 'References' | sort | uniq | xargs yum -y update
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the plugin called  yum-plugin-security. The commands give you the security information.

## yum -y install yum-plugin-security

Comment: No, this will not work. It will always give you empty list of updates, CentOS does not provide security metadata. This only works in RHEL.